# не выводится ответ

Tags: c++, borland-c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    double x,b,F,s,f;
    int k=0;
    x=StrToFloat(Edit1->Text);
    b=StrToFloat(Edit2->Text);

    if (RadioButton1->Checked==true)
    {
        F=sin(x);
        k=1;
    }

    if (RadioButton2->Checked==true)
    {
        F=pow(x,2);
        k=2;
    }

    if (RadioButton3->Checked==true)
    {
        F=exp(x);
        k=3;
    }

    if ((x*b)>1 && (x*b)<10)
        s=exp(f);

    if ((x*b)>=12 && (x*b)<40)
        s=sqrt((abs(f+(4*b))));
    else
        s=b*pow(f,2);

    if(k==1)
        Memo1->Lines->Add("sin(x)="+FloatToStrF(s,ffFixed,8,6));

    if(k==2)
        Memo1->Lines->Add("x^2="+FloatToStrF(s,ffFixed,8,6));

    if(k==3)
        Memo1->Lines->Add("e^x="+FloatToStrF(s,ffFixed,8,6));
}
```

Comment: А под выводом вы подразумеваете что в Memo ничего не появляется?

Comment: Нет, то, что вместо вычислений выдаются одни нули

Comment: Отладчик использовать не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовали, но не особо помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас явно нет понимания того, что это такое и как это работает. Из разных программ надёргали? Вначале присваиваем значение `F`, а потом про него забываем и используем неинициализированное `f`. Да и проверка условий неверная. Нужно как-то так:

```
double x, b, F, s;

// ...

if ((x*b)>1 && (x*b)<10)
    s=exp(F);
else if ((x*b)>=12 && (x*b)<40)
    s=sqrt((abs(F+(4*b))));
else
    s=b*pow(F,2);
```

P.S. А за конструкцию `pow(x,2)` в приличном обществе бьют канделябром и пишут `x*x`.

Comment: Всегда хотел спросить, не существует ли перегруженной (шаблона) pow для целочисленной степени, которая различала бы  pow(x, 2) и pow(x, 2.0)?

Comment: @BuilderC В *GCC* есть какая-то внутренняя оптимизация `pow` по типу аргументов.